# Using autofs to mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 to /media/autousb

Tags: sd-card, autofs

I am trying to automount an internal sd card reader when the sd card is inserted into a laptop.  I have already been able to get external SD card readers to automount once the card is inserted, and an Iphone to automount using ifuse. Below are the following commands when the card is inserted:

**fdisk -l**
*/dev/mmcblk0p1  8192 31116287 3110896 14.9g c W95 FAT32 (LBA)*

**blkid**
*/dev/mmcblk0p1: UUID="3434-6531" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTTYPE="dos"*

After card is inserted I run dmesg:

**dmesg**
mmc0: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address aaaa

mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB (ro)

mmcblk0: p1

The Following information is how I am mounting the others that are working, and would love to append to something to get the internal card reader to work, assuming it's possible. Or can I add another auto.foo file and use auto.master to call it?

In the /etc/auto.master file:

- auto.master
  /media/autousb /etc/autofs/auto.usb

In the /etc/autofs/auto.usb file: (that is currently working with the usb and iphone automounts)

key=${1}
fstype=$(/sbin/blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/usbdisks/${key})

if [ "$fstype}" = "vfat" ]; then

```
echo "-fstype=vfat,sync,uid=0,gid=1000,umask=007 :/dev/usbdiskss/${key})"
exit 0
```

else

```
echo "-fstype=exfat,sync,uid=0,gid=1000,umask=007 :/dev/usbdisks/${key}"
exit 0
```

fi

exit 1

I am able to mount the device from the command line with the following command once the card is inserted:

**mount -t vfat -o defaults,rw,dmask=007,fmask=117,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/autousb**

All I need to do is read the card as I put the contents of the media into another directory, so "read only is not an issue"

My mount point is: **/media/autousb**

Output of /dev after card is inserted with ls -ltr /dev is: **brw-rw---- 1 root   disk  179,   0 Date mmcblk0**

and **brw-rw---- 1 root   disk  179,   0 Date mmcblk0p1**

Output of /dev/block also shows **179:0 -> ../mmcblk0**

and **179:1 -> mmcblk0p1**

I am sorry if I have not formatted this correctly and I hope I have given enough information for you to be able to make sense of what I am asking. I have tried so many different things after so many google searches and they just don't seem to work.

Thanks in advance, and hope you all are well.
John